# Reducing splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If we have splitting field:

$$L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{6}},\sqrt{2-i\sqrt{6}}) $$

we can multiply these two zeroes and get $\sqrt{10}$ so we have

$$L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{6}},\sqrt{10})$$

Can we reduce it a little more and write $\sqrt{10}=\sqrt{5}\sqrt{2}$ so $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{6}},\sqrt{5})$?

I have one additional question here. Can we take $(\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{6}})^2$ and then reduce it like $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{6}},i \sqrt{6})$?

Comment: Is it obvious that $\sqrt{2}\in L$?

Comment: No, I think it is not.

Answer (score 2):

It is not obvious. In fact, I'd say that is false.

*If* it is true, you must show that $\sqrt 2\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{6}},\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: I agree, I tried and I can not show that. Maybe I'm making a mistake somewhere but I'm pretty sure it's not true. Thank You.

Comment: Can we take $\sqrt{2+i \sqrt{6}}^2$ and then get $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i \sqrt{6}}, i \sqrt{6})$? It seems right but when I try to find extension degree of L over Q, I get 4 where it should be 8.